# INSERT... WHERE NOT EXISTS error

Tags: php, mysql

I have syntax error with my code

```
$insert = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO topics (t_title, t_desc, t_pic, t_link, t_date,cat_id)
SELECT '$t_title','$t_desc','$t_pic','$t_link','$t_date','$cat_id'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t_link
FROM topics
WHERE t_link = $t_link
) 
")or die(mysql_error());
```

This returns an error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t_link FROM topics WHERE t_link = 'showthread.php?t=120' at line 3
```

I thought that the problem is with t_link = $t_link

But when i replaced it with normal value , the problem persists.

Any help ?

Comment: Should `WHERE t_link = $t_link` not be `WHERE t_link = '$t_link'`?

Comment: @dunc i tried this but not working.

Comment: please, change: die(mysql_error()); by die(echo($insert)); and post clean sql query.

Comment: Is `t_link` a unique key in the `topics` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `FROM` on first SELECT

```
SELECT '$t_title','$t_desc','$t_pic','$t_link','$t_date','$cat_id'
# MISSED HERE FROM ???
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

Comment: this is php variables. how can i write FROM ?

Comment: @chumkiu. No! perhaps chas thousend of rows!

Comment: @danihp when using from dual another error appear :    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?t=120 )' at line 6

Comment: @danihp the error is the missed `from` sure... but what he want to do I don't know :-) He can insert a limit 1 maybe :-)

Comment: @DrZIZO  `WHERE t_link = '$t_link'` <-- see the quotes too

Comment: @chumkiu also    FROM topics not working same error as from dual

Comment: @chumkiu when using `FROM topics` and `'$t_link'` it works but it inserts about 100 duplicates of the same topic!! SHOULD I REMOVE `FROM topics` ??

Comment: @danihp If topics grows much bigger , will it affect site speed ? is there another way (less server load) ?

Comment: @chumkiu where to put `limit 1` ? after `from topics` or `where not exists` ?

Comment: Maybe you need some additional conditions in your WHERE clause to tell it which rows from `dual` to insert into `topics`. Adding `LIMIT 1` will just pick a random row.

Comment: @DrZIZO, main problem is if one day `topic` table has no rows. No rows means no insert. For this reason, I suggest to you to use `dual` table. ['You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are referenced'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: @danihp I just used this and it works exactly as i need : `$insert = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO topics (t_title, t_desc, t_pic, t_link, t_date, cat_id)
SELECT '$t_title','$t_desc','$t_pic','$t_link','$t_date','$cat_id'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t_link
FROM topics 
WHERE t_link = '$t_link'
) 
")or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @DrZIZO, nice, check as solution chumkiu answer or read new Barmar post.

Answer (score 1):

Here solution for FROM CLAUSE, please, check as solution chumkiu's answer, not mine.

```
create table a ( i int);

insert into a (i )
select 1
from dual
where 1=2;

insert into a (i )
select 3
from dual
where 1=1;
```

[Results](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b75a3/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

If `t_link` is has a unique index in the table, you can do:

```
$insert = @mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO topics (t_title, t_desc, t_pic, t_link, t_date,cat_id)
    VALUES ('$t_title','$t_desc','$t_pic','$t_link','$t_date','$cat_id');
```

The `IGNORE` keyword tells it to do nothing if the insert would duplicate a unique key constraint.